# How to resolve the version incompatibility between the jars in /storm/lib and jar that is submitted to storm cluster (jar-with-dependencies)

Tags: maven, apache-storm

I have a Topology that reads data from kafka using kafka-spout and pushes the processed data to elasticsearch. I have used, elasticsearch-2.3.3 client. And it requires guava-18.0 jar dependency. I have formed a jar-with-dependencies using maven. After submitting the topology to storm, i got below error

**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor; at org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool.(ThreadPool.java:190)**

After searching about the above error, got to know that this is due to mismatch of guava jar. I checked the storm server, where i found guava-15 in its /lib folder. Since other topologies are using guava-15.jar, i cannot upgrade it directly to guava-18.

Is there a way, where I can resolve this dependencies, by specifying guava-18 path exclusively for my topology while submitting.

Comment: Yes,  you can add exclusions in your dependency POM for guava15 and include as a direct dependency in your POM.xml for guava18. If you use eclipse IDE/other ide you can manage this conflicts and the dependencies view level.

Comment: I have added direct dependency for guava-18 in pom.xml, however i haven't explicitly added any exclusions for guava-15 dependency in POM. 
And i am using command line arguments to submit topology to storm cluster.

Comment: Please add exclusions and let know, will update as an answer

Comment: I tried the above method. Still getting the same exception. I added  exclusion for guava (since we cannot specify version in <exclusion>). and then a direct dependency on guava-18. Still the same.

Comment: Please post your pom.xml